# Mapping N to N relationships with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, database, postgresql, automapper, ef-core-2.0

I'm making a little example with c#, automapper and postgreSQL ef core.
My entities are clients, products, sales, sales_products.

I already made the mapping of clients and products but i don't know how to map the n to n relationship between sales and products.

Here is my code:

Sales entity:

```
public partial class Sales
{
    public Sales()
    {
        SalesProducts = new HashSet<SalesProducts>();
    }

    public int SaleId { get; set; }
    public int? ClientId { get; set; }
    public float TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

    public Clients Client { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SalesProducts> SalesProducts { get; set; }
}
```

Products entity:

```
public partial class Products
{
    public Products()
    {
        SalesProducts = new HashSet<SalesProducts>();
    }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
    public int Quant { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SalesProducts> SalesProducts { get; set; }
}
```

SalesProducts entity:

```
public partial class SalesProducts
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int SaleId { get; set; }
    public int? Quantity { get; set; }

    public Products Product { get; set; }
    public Sales Sale { get; set; }
}
```

Products Model:

```
public class Products
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
    public int Quant { get; set; }
}
```

Sales Model:

```
public class Sales
{
    public int SaleId { get; set; }
    public Clients Client { get; set; }
    public float TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

    public List<Products> Product { get; set; }
}
```

SalesProducts Model:

```
public class SalesProducts
{
    public int SaleId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Quant { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to make a mapping but it was always giving an error about unmapped product:

```
public class SalesProfiles : Profile
{
    public SalesProfiles()
    {
        CreateMap<DataModels.SalesProducts, Models.SalesProducts>();

        CreateMap<DataModels.Sales, Models.SalesProducts>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.SaleId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SaleId))
            .ReverseMap();

        CreateMap<DataModels.Products, Models.SalesProducts>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ProductId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ProductId))
            .ReverseMap();

        CreateMap<DataModels.Sales, Models.Sales>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.SaleId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SaleId))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Client, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Client))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Date, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Date))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.TotalPrice, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TotalPrice))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Product, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SalesProducts.Select(x => x.Product).ToList()));
    }
}
```

Products mapping:

```
public class ProductsProfiles : Profile
{
    public ProductsProfiles()
    {
        CreateMap<Models.Products, BindingModels.Products>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ProductName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ProductName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Description, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Description))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Quant, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Quant))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Price, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Price))
            .ReverseMap();

        CreateMap<Models.Products, DataModels.Products>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ProductId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ProductId))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ProductName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ProductName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Description, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Description))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Quant, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Quant))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Price, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Price))
            .ReverseMap();

        CreateMap<BindingModels.Products, DataModels.Products>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ProductName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ProductName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Description, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Description))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Quant, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Quant))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Price, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Price))
            .ReverseMap();

        CreateMap<DataModels.Products, Models.Products>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ProductId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ProductId))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ProductName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ProductName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Description, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Description))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Quant, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Quant))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Price, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Price))
            .ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

Clients Mapping:

```
public class ClientsProfiles : Profile
{
    public ClientsProfiles()
    {
        CreateMap<Models.Clients, BindingModels.Clients>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FirstName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LastName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.BirthDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.BirthDate))
            .ReverseMap();

        CreateMap<Models.Clients, DataModels.Clients>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ClientId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ClientId))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FirstName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LastName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.BirthDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.BirthDate))
            .ReverseMap();

        CreateMap<BindingModels.Clients, DataModels.Clients>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FirstName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LastName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.BirthDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.BirthDate))
            .ReverseMap();

        CreateMap<DataModels.Clients, Models.Clients>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ClientId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ClientId))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FirstName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LastName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.BirthDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.BirthDate))
            .ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

Does somebody knows how can i map this properly?

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to make a mapping but it was always giving an error about
>   unmapped product:

You've defined a map for how to map your two `SalesProducts` classes, but they have different properties so you will need to define how you expect those properties to be mapped.

`CreateMap<DataModels.SalesProducts, Models.SalesProducts>();`

Specifically, one of your `SalesProducts` has a `Product` and `Sale` property that the other one doesn't have. You could mark it as ignore, because otherwise how are you expecting to create it from a class that doesn't have those properties?

You also don't have a mapping to go from `DataModels.Product` to `Models.Product` ... this may be your error.

Comment: I made the products and clients mapping in another files, i published them now